# Is there a better way to setup the input checked attribute?

Tags: javascript, php

My first thought was to set the input checked = "javascript function() true/false" is this possible?

What I am trying to do is a select all checkbox for my forum mailbox system.

I am useing a table to display the inbox and placed the select all checkbox inside.

```
<form action="" method = "post">
<table rules="all">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" id = "setchecked" name="smessgage"value="deleteall" onclick="get_checked()"/>
    </th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
```

I use

```
onclick="get_checked()
```

to call this javascript function which sets the other checkboxes checked attribute.

```
<script>
function get_checked()
{
    if(document.getElementById("setchecked").checked)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100;++i)
        {
            var check_id = "smessage"+i;
            if(document.getElementById(check_id))
            document.getElementById(check_id).checked = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100;++i)
        {
            var check_id = "smessage"+i;
            if(document.getElementById(check_id))
            document.getElementById(check_id).checked = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The php to set the table up looks like this.

```
$i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        if(isset($row['to_']) && $row['to_'] == $_SESSION['user_name'])
        {
            $id_ = isset($row['id']) ? $row['id'] : '';
            $top_ = isset($row['subject']) ? $row['subject'] : '';
            $auth_ = isset($row['from_']) ? $row['from_'] : '';
            $date_ = isset($row['date']) ? $row['date'] : '';


            echo '<tr id = "cat_" name = "cat_1">
            <td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" id = "smessage'.$i.'" name="smessgage" value="'.$id_.'"/></td>
            <td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:center;"><a href = "mail?from='.$auth_.'&mail_id='.$id_.'&mail_name='.$top_.'">'.
            $auth_.'</a></td>
            <td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:center;"><a href = "mail?from='.$auth_.'&mail_id='.$id_.'&mail_name='.$top_.'">'.
            $top_.'</a></td>
            <td style = "margin:0 auto; text-align:center;"><a href = "mail?from='.$auth_.'&mail_id='.$id_.'&mail_name='.$top_.'">'.
            time_elapsed_string($date_,true).'</a></td></tr>';
            ++$i;
        }
    }
```

This works as expected but seems a bit overkill. I just want to know if there is a more relastic approach or something that I missed while looking over input types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your improved version. Basically you just need to use same class for all checkbox before each line of your message, so that you can use jQuery.each() function to select all and toggle the checked property based on your main checkbox, which has id "setchecked"

Hope this help,

KD Quality

```js
function checkAll(bx) {
  var cbs = jQuery(".checkbox_class").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).prop('checked', jQuery('#setchecked').prop('checked'));
  });
}

var e = document.getElementById('setchecked'); e.onclick = checkAll;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <table rules="all">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="setchecked" name="smessgage" value="deleteall" />
      </th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="messgage[]" value="message_1" class="checkbox_class" />
      </td>
      <td>Message 1</td>
      <td>Message 1</td>
      <td>Some Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="messgage[]" value="message_2" class="checkbox_class" />
      </td>
      <td>Message 1</td>
      <td>Message 1</td>
      <td>Some Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="messgage[]" value="message_3" class="checkbox_class" />
      </td>
      <td>Message 1</td>
      <td>Message 1</td>
      <td>Some Date</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you that is very nice. I am trying to stick with pure javascript but this Jquery function is awsome I will use it. I love to reduce code where ever possible and this will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
// The important code
function selectAll(e) {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('form input[type=checkbox]');
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].checked = e.target.checked;
  };
}

// This is only code to genereate input elements
var form = document.getElementById('foo');
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "checkbox";
  form.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<input id="selectall" type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll(event)" />
<label for="selectall">Select all</label>
<hr />
<form id="foo"></form>
```

Comment: This is also exactly what I needed If I could give you an upvote or accept multiple answers I would.Thank you for your time.